# WebContentTypeMapper: Determine if I am receiving or responding to a request

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service which uses a WebContentTypeMapper in order to allow different signatures in my interface. Now I found out that the WebContentTypeMapper is called 3 times for a single POST request. 2 times before and once after processing my OperationContract.

How can I determine within the WebContentTypeMapper if I am getting the request or already responding to it?

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.Web;

public class RawContentTypeMapper : WebContentTypeMapper
{
    public override WebContentFormat GetMessageFormatForContentType(string contentType)
    {
        string pathInfo;
        try
        {
            pathInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.PathInfo;
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            pathInfo = null;
        }
        switch (pathInfo)
        {
            case "/rest/myoperationcontract1":
                return WebContentFormat.Raw; // This allows to define an operationcontract with parameter of type Stream where we can read the body of the request.
            default:
                return WebContentFormat.Default; // No change to default behavior
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the intent of `WebContentTypeMapper` is to **Specify the format to which the content type of an __incoming message__ is mapped.** So definitely you're reciving the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Amit Kumar Ghosh explained that the mapping is only used for incoming messages, an answer is no longer required. I just wondered why the mapper is called after processing the request.